# VBScript for removing rows in excel based on empty column values

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'm a VBScript learner. I'm trying to delete the rows if a particular column's cell value is empty in excel.  This is the snippet which I've written.

```
set mysheet1 = myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 
Row1=mysheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For  i= 1 to Row1
  If len(mysheet1.cells(i,1).value) = 0 then
          mysheet1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next
```

Unfortunately it's not deleting the rows. What might be the issue? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Go backwards**

Replace:

```
For  i= 1 to Row1
```

with:

```
For  i= Row1 to 1 Step -1
```

**EDIT#1:**

The reason that when we delete rows, we always go from bottom to top is that if we went the other way *(the natural way)* the loop indexing gets messed up.

Say we are going top-to-bottom and  just examined and deleted row #5; we would like to examine row #6 next, but the delete changed it to row #5.  This causes us to missing examining the old row #6 entirely!.

When we go from bottom-to-top, deleting rows does not affect the loop.

Comment: please help me to understand the about change. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @arunpandiyarajhen  See my **EDIT#1**